# EXT JS 5: viewModel links variable id

Tags: hyperlink, extjs5

I am using Ext JS 5.0.1 and I am trying to use links in the viewModel defined inside a view.

The example below works.

```
Ext.define("MyViewPackage.MyView", {
extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
alias: "widget.myview",
theIdToUse: 47,
    viewModel: {
        links: {
            theProject: {
                type 'mypackage.MyModelClassName'
                id: 17 //This works. But not theIdToUse  or this.theIdToUse.
                       //I would like to use a value provided from my view
            }   
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to use the value of 'theIdToUse' for the id property of 'theProject' defined in 'links'.
I have tried to simply put ***theIdToUse*** or this.theIdToUse but I always got the following error:

**Cannot use bind config without a viewModel**

Do you know how could I managed to use links with a variable id?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use `linkTo`, like:

```
Ext.define("MyViewPackage.MyView", {
  extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
  alias: "widget.myview",
  theIdToUse: 47,

  constructor: function(){
    this.callParent(arguments);

    this.linkTo('theProject',{
      type 'mypackage.MyModelClassName',
      id: this.theIdToUse
    });

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this.theIdToUse does not work because within the scope of the viewModel, *this* no longer refers to MyViewPackage.MyView, but to the viewModel itself.

Even if you could get a reference back to MyViewPackage.MyView, say using ComponentQuery, the component does not yet exist at the point that the viewModel is being initialized, so you will get an error *Cannot read property 'theIdToUse' of undefined*.

You would probably be better off using some sort of two way binding between the view and viewModel, but I would need to know more about what you're trying to achieve to say exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer were pretty correct, except that in your case `this` would refer to window, not `viewModel`. This is due to in `Ext.define` you are passing anonymous object without some scope, so `window` scope would be used by default. 
Suppose you should use something like this:

```
Ext.define("MyViewPackage.MyView", {
extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
alias: "widget.myview",
bind: {theIdToUse: "{id}"}
viewModel: {
    links: {
        theProject: {
            type 'mypackage.MyModelClassName'
            id: 17 //This works. But not theIdToUse  or this.theIdToUse.
                   //I would like to use a value provided from my view
        }   
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is from long time ago, I leave a possible solution for further viewers.

Try:

```
Ext.define("MyViewPackage.MyView", {
extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
alias: "widget.myview",
    config: {
        theIdToUse: 47,
    },
    viewModel: {
        links: {
            theProject: {
                type 'mypackage.MyModelClassName'
                id: null // Will be copied from config in initConfig
            }   
        }
    },

    initConfig: function (config) {
        this.config.viewModel.links.theProject.id = config.theIdToUse ;
        this.callParent([config]) ;
    }
});
```

You will be able to instanciate your panel with different ids:

```
items: [
  {
    xtype: 'myview',
    theIdToUse: 47
  },{
    xtype: 'myview',
    theIdToUse: 32
  }
],
```

Even with:

```
Ext.create('MyViewPackage.MyView', {theIdToUse: 12}) ;
```